# Issues with Ajax, preventDefault script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to build a script file to prevent the default action of the form.  When the search button is clicked, a "loading" indicator image is suppose to be shown and a table is suppose to appear below the button.  I cannot get the ajax "loading" indicator image to appear nor the table.  Can someone please help me?  Here is my code:

EquipmentScript.js

```
$(function () {
$("#equipmentSearch").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#ajax-loader").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#ajax-loader").hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var html = Mustache.to_html($("#itemTemplate").html(),
                    {db.Equipment});

        }
    });
});
```

});

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <!--Index method in the EquipmentModel controller-->
    <form id="equipmentSearch" method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index", "EquipmentModel")">
        <button id="process" value="search" class="btn btn-info">Search For Equipment</button>
        <img id="ajax-loader" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" style="display:none" />
    </form>
    <script id="equipmentTemplate" type="text/html">
    </script>
    <div id="searchresults"></div>
</div>
```

The Index method in the EquipmentModel Controller is like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Equipments.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with your server-side code, show the HTML that gets sent to the browser (not the cshtml producing it), and no need to quote the irrelevant server-side code.

Comment: *"I cannot get the ajax "loading" indicator image to appear"* It *should* appear. Do you get any errors in the console? Can you create a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) using `setTimeout` to simulate the ajax?